# Sending an email with an attachment via PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm having trouble getting PHPMailer to send out an email with an image attachment that a user submits. I just keep getting "Mail Error" everytime it tries to send. I just can't see what is going wrong. There's no errors in the error_log, it just fails everytime.

HTML Input dealing with image attachment:

```
<input type="file" name="file" placeholder="Choose an image." id="imageupload" accept="image/jpeg" />
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php

// Make sure logged in
include('../php_scripts/login-required.php');
// Make sure posted
if (!$_POST) {
    header('location: ./404.php');
}
// Include PHPmailer
require 'site_includes/PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php';

// Get variables
$offertype = $_POST['ot'];
if ($offertype == 1) {
    $offertype = 'Discount';
} elseif ($offertype == 2) {
    $offertype = 'Free';
} else {
    $offertype = 'Not set';
}
$offerdetail = $_POST['od'];
// Check for errors
if (!isset($offertype) || empty($offertype)) {
    $errors = 1;
    header('location: ./create-advert.php?errors=' . $errors . '&ot=' . $offertype . '&od=' . $offerdetail);
} elseif (!isset($offerdetail) || empty($offerdetail)) {
    $errors = 2;
    header('location: ./create-advert.php?errors=' . $errors . '&ot=' . $offertype . '&od=' . $offerdetail);
}

// Get variables from database
include('../php_scripts/db-connect.php');
include('../php_scripts/get-userinfo.php');

// Set mail variables
$reply      = $email;
$replyname  = $fullname;
$to         = 'test@example.com';
$toname     = 'John Doe';
$from       = 'example@example.com';
$subject    = 'New Advert Request';
$message    = 'Name: ' . $fullname . "\r\n" . "Company: " . $company . "\r\n" . "Phone: " . $phone . "\r\n" . "Email: " . $email . "\r\n\r\n" . $offertype . "\r\n" . "--------------------------------------------------" . "\r\n\r\n" . $offerdetail;

if (isset($_FILES['file'])) {

    // Get attachment and upload
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "uploads/$name");

    // Send email with attachment
    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    $mail->From = $from;
    $mail->addAddress($to, $toname);
    $mail->addReplyTo($reply, $replyname);
    $mail->WordWrap = 50;
    $mail->addAttachment(
        '/uploads/' . $name,
        $name,
        'base64',
        'mime/type'
    );
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->AltBody = $message;

    if (!$mail->send()) {
        echo 'Mail Error!';
        exit;
    } else {
        echo 'Message has been sent!';
    }
}
```

?>

I also know I should be creating an array for acceptable  file extensions (only .jpg or .jpeg in this case), but am also unsure of exactly how and where to implement these.

Also, I only changed the $to and $from emails. Why would this always be failing to send? All I'm looking to do is send a plain text email either with an email attachment or without one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to send file from the root `/uploads` directory:

```
$mail->addAttachment(
    '/uploads/' . $name,
```

It will be easier to send email before moving the file, passing `$tmp_name` as a first parameter to `addAttachment()` method. Or, optionally, make sure to specify correct path to the file after you have moved it to uploads dir. (wild guess: `"./uploads/$name"` - dot means current dir).

Also, you can try to check `$mail->ErrorInfo` for details of your error.

Comment: I was under the impression that the file had to be placed somewhere like an uploads folder before sending it out through email. I just tried passing in the $tmp_name like you suggested and the email finally went through but without the attachment (after commenting out the move_uploaded_file bit).

Comment: File uploaded by the users and files sent out as an email attachments with phpmailer are completely independent. PHPMailer needs to know where file is located - full path to read it and attach. So, your task is to pass correct file path to AddAttachment method. If you were moving the file just to send it, remove that file manipulation code completely and simply use `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']` as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks! This has been bugging me for the past day.